# Leaking stand-up fiberglass shower

Tags: shower, fiberglass, leaks

I have a small stand-up fiberglass shower that is leaking water into my closet which is right next to it. I have pulled back the carpet and dried the water up, but it keeps leaking water. Even after no water has been ran for well over 15 hours. This is also the opposite wall to where the faucet is for the shower. I can't even begin to try and solve the problem if I can't get the water to stop. Any ideas? Could it have something to do with the pressure relief valve on the hot water heater?

Comment: If it leaks when no-one is running the shower, the you're going to have to get behind/underneath to find what's leaking - as it's obviously not the shower tray or other visible component.

Comment: Hi, it's not clear what does the hot water heater have to do with your shower. Is it located right next to it? Some pictures of the situation would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

Check the supply line and associated fittings, because of the 15 hour time interval I doubt it is a drain. If it is in a wall maybe you can put some newspaper through the shower escutcheon plate and valve as well as under the pressure relief valve.
After a few hours remove it and see if it is dry, if not you know where your problem is.
You can buy a fiber optic camera maybe 3 meters or so in length from your favourite china supplier for not much and plug it into your laptop. Use that to probe in the wall and find out what you can see. Start at the shower valve or where there is already access. At this point you should know where the problem is and take appropriate steps to repair. To be sure on the drain you can put some dye in the shower and rinse down in the drain.